# Ajax call to web api is Not Working

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I'm new to Ajax,I've written my Api in get method it's return value sucessfully i've seen it on web console and also in fiddler but my ajax call to web api is not get any values at document ready function and also not get any error in browser console i don't known why, any one please help me here i attach my api and ajax call.

Api:

```
[Route("api/GetCompanyName")]
[HttpGet]
public List<Company> GetCompanyName()
{
    var Compname = getcompName();

    return Compname;
}

public List<Company> getcompName()
{
    var CompName = new List<Company>();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnString);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From Company_table", con);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        CompName.Add(new Company
        {
            companyname = dr["Company_mtName"].ToString(),
            //value = dr["Company_Name"].ToString()
        });
    }
    con.Close();

    return CompName;
}
```

Ajax call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url:'192.168.1.6:68/api/GetCompanyName',
            type:'GET',
            dataType:'JSON',                                
            crossDomain:true,       

            success: function(data,xhr){
                alert(data);
                }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `192.168.1.6:68/api/GetCompanyName` Missing `http://`?

Comment: For cross domain you may need use JSONP rather than JSON

Comment: try url http://localhost:68/api/GetCompanyName

Comment: @MadOX tell me about jsonp please

Comment: Its like a regular JSON, codewise all js same. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: @DhavalMarthak 192.168.1.6:68 and http://  192.168.1.6:68 all are same thing..

Comment: @MadOX for adding jsonp in web api any namespace reference is needed?

Comment: No still return JSON

Comment: @MadOX ok thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allow cross domain access in api. For that you need to use `System.Web.Http.Cors library`.

```
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

[HttpGet]
[EnableCors("*", "*", "GET")]
public List<Company> GetCompanyName()
{
var Compname = getcompName();
return Compname;
}
```

In cors first parameter is your host name. " * " means any host can access the method.Second parameter is header and third one is type. " * " can be used to make the method to allow both POST and GET.

Comment: @santhosh [Read here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) for more details on cors

Comment: @inthevortex - The website is nice. It gives understandable and complete details about CORS

Comment: Thanks both of you  ,I made it with Jsonp method in my controller it works fine,I will read about Cors may be it's useful in future. :)

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks ok to me, have you tried adding an error callback as the final param and see if anything happens there?

you can also add a 
debugger;
statement into your code, that will allow you to step through your code and make sure everything is acting accordingly.. debugger style.. (just make sure you have your browsers dev tools open (f12))..

that can help make sure that everything is getting called.

also can you hit that url with a browser and get back data?

Comment: Thanks for your reply , No,i won't try error callback function after success callback,i may try it later and see what error will getting,yes i will hit that url and got data back and also i check it on fiddler too that's work good but ajax call did't get any value :(

Comment: you can also add a breakpoint through your browser's dev tools if you cannot add a debugger statement to the code.  that will help make sure you are hitting the code.  i'm not sure you're hitting the code still?  maybe just add an alert after the call to make sure you are hitting the code?

Comment: after adding error function i'm getting error alert,success function is not working.how to see detailed error in browser i'm using firefox

Comment: something like this:error: function(err){
                alert(err);
                }

Comment: you can also checkout the console section of the firefox dev tools to see any errors

Answer (score 1):

try the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url:"192.168.1.6:68/api/GetCompanyName",
        type:"GET",
        dataType:"application/json",                                
        crossDomain:true,       

        success: function(data,xhr){
            alert(data);
            }
    });
});
```

also try with looping the data. Since it is a class object, JSON may not properly show you. Use `$.each` and loop the data